# TestNG Installation

Tags: eclipse, testng

I have been trying to install TestNG to my Eclipse.
Eclipse version is Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)..
While trying to install, it shows the error as mentioned below.
Please guide me how to rectify this problem.

> **An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Unable to read repository at
>   http://beust.com/eclipse/plugins/org.testng.eclipse_6.9.10.201512240000.jar.
>   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected:
>   3005134; received: 1555400**

Answer (score 0):

If it looks like some thing went wrong...

Follow below steps

Help >> Eclipse MarketPlace >>  Search for TestNG and then install it.

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

My this problem got solved by "Not downloading Optional TestNG" part (i.e Dont download "TestNG M2E Integration (Optional)" if not needed(It's recommended to install it if your Java project(s) are managed by Maven))